# Obtener un campo blob en formato binario desde un resultSet en Mysql con Java

Tags: java, mysql, insert, blob

Cuando realizo DUMP de una tabla en MySQL, si tiene un campo blob, me genera un INSERT con el siguiente formato:

```
INSERT INTO `fotos` VALUES (1,73,_binary 'ÿ\Øÿ\à\0JFIF\....')
```

Quisiera que mi aplicación genere ese comando INSERT para realizar mi propio DUMP desde mi aplicación java.

Mi duda es como obtengo la cadena binaria que va después del ***_binary*** a partir de un ***ResultSet*** que me entrega el ***statement.executeQuery(sql)*** ??

Yo llego a obtener el blob del campo:

```
Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(i);
```

pero no se como obtener el string que necesito a partir de ahi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se que criterio usa para armar el string _binary, algunos caracteres los escapa y otros no. Así que desistí de usar ese formato.

Resolví mi problema obteniendo el campo BLOB en base64 y armando el INSERT con ..., FROM_BASE64(...).

Para obtener el blob en base64 desde el resultSet hago:

```
Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(i);
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
String base64 = bytes2base(bytes);
```

y el insert queda:

```
INSERT INTO `fotos` VALUES (1,73,FROM_BASE64('...base64...');
```

Todo esto para poder hacer mi propio DUMP de la base.